# Implementing editing in ASP.NET DataGrid when data comes from several related tables

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, sqldatasource

Today while working on one of my client's project I came up with an issue for which I am unable to figure out the solution. So I am Throwing it on to you guys.

I am using a databound GridView Control, the code for the SqlDataSource for the same is :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_familyMembers" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VBAT_dbConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="
       select 
          a.memberid,a.fristName,a.lastname,a.gender,a.dob,
          b.relation as [Relation with Family Head],
      c.districtname,d.statename,e.countryname,a.mobno,f.occupation,a.ismaried 
      from 
         family_members_info as a
      left outer join
         master_relations as b
      on
         a.RelationWithFamilyHead=b.relationid
      join
         master_district as c
      on 
         a.cadistrict=c.districtid
      join
         master_state as d
      on 
        a.castate=d.stateid
     join
        master_country as e
     on 
        a.cacountry=e.countryid
     join
       master_occupation as f
     on
       a.occupation=f.occupationid
     where 
         familyid=@familyid" 
   UpdateCommand="
         update 
             family_members_info 
         set                    
            firstName=@firstname, lastname=@lastName, dob=@dob,
            relationwithfamilyhead=@relationwithfamilyhead,cadistrict=@cadistrict, 
            castate=@castate, cacountry=@cacountry,mobno=@mobno,occupation=@occupation 
         where 
            memberID=@memberID">
  <SelectParameters>                    
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="familyid"   PropertyName="Value" />
  </SelectParameters>
  <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="firstname"  />
      <asp:Parameter Name="lastName" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="dob" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="relationwithfamilyhead" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="cadistrict" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="castate" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="cacountry" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="mobno" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="occupation" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="memberID" />
   </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you can see from Select query that, the data comes from several related tables, everything works fine except when user want to edit data.

For all the columns, by default, GridView displays textbox, while it should display DropdownList for the columns which are foreign keys.

I would be great help if anybody can guide me a possible solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you're looking for follow these *high level* steps:

1. Template your grid view - Create `TemplateField` items for each column in your grid view, for both `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate`
2. For id fields specify the control type for `EditItemTemplate` to be a `DropDownList`
3. Create a `SqlDataSource` or any other data binding method of your choice and bind it to the `DropDownList` to retrieve the ids and value from the required table
4. Set the `DataValueField` of the `DropDownList` to be the **id** and `DataTextField` to be the **display value**

Here's a working example of the points above - [Filtering Dropdownlist populated from sqldatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303297/filtering-dropdownlist-populated-from-sqldatasource/13323595#13323595)

Comment: Implemented. Thanks for the help, Sir.